# Want to use Dynamic Jasper to make Reports with my Db MYSQL

Tags: web-services, netbeans

I want to Use Dynamic Jasper to create reports of my database i.e mySQL.

Plus, I want to know that can I send attributes to Dynamic Jasper which a user is going to select from the front end based on XHTML MP and then I want Dynamic Jasper to make report on the selected attributes.

P.S.: I m sending selected attributes through Servlet to Dynamic Jasper

Answer (score 0):

You are already answering it

The receiving servlet, lets call it `ReportingTestServlet`, this servlet will receive the attributes from the front end.

Create a utility class lets call it `ReportGenerator`, I prefer to use utility classes to make things more maintainable if you want to add more reports to the servlet later. This class will look something like this [Fixed Column Width Test](http://dynamicjasper.sourceforge.net/xref-test/ar/com/fdvs/dj/test/FixedColumnWidhTest.html), this is a sample from DJ. Mainly the class will take the parameters and return a `DynamicReport` object.

Finally you will write something like [DjReportTest](http://dynamicjasper.sourceforge.net/xref-test/ar/com/fdvs/dj/test/BaseDjReportTest.html) that takes the `DynamicReport` and using JasperReport API create a `JasperPrint` object, this object could be easily exported to PDF/HTML/RTF from the JasperReport API

Hope that helps